# Android FrameLayout is not replace by Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

This app contains `activity_main.xml`, `mainactivit.java` and one Fragment class.
`activity_main.xml` has one Button and `FrameLayout` inside  `RelativeLayout`.
When the Button is clicked, `FrameLayout` should be replaced by fragments, but it doesn't get replaced.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="loadd"
            android:text="Fragment No.2" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/maincontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**mainactivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void loadd(View v) {
        try {
            Fragment fragment = new fr();
            FragmentManager frgManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction trans = frgManager.beginTransaction();
            trans.replace(R.id.maincontainer, fragment);
            trans.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

**Fragment class**

```
public class fr extends Fragment{
    public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inf,ViewGroup parent,Bundle save){
        return inf.inflate(R.layout.send,parent, false);
        }
}
```

**send.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textmsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

There is no compile time or run time error, but when I click that Button `the FrameLayout` is not replaced by the `Fragment`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that you posted looks good, except you aren't overriding `Fragment.onCreateView`, instead you've made a typo.

**What you have**

```
public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup parent, Bundle save) {
    return inf.inflate(R.layout.test, parent, false);
}
```

**What you should have**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inf, ViewGroup parent, Bundle save) {
    return inf.inflate(R.layout.test, parent, false);
}
```

Pay close attention to the name of the method. It should begin with a lowercase "o".